# Indice issue loading lists into Postgres with python

Tags: python, postgresql

My code takes input from a json file and parses out the json object into lists this works when I try to insert those lists into the sql with the executemany command it is throwing this error

```
 string indices must be integers
```

Checking with print statements shows all the lists are, in fact lists and loaded correctly not sure what to do to proceed

here is my code

```
 def insert_item_manifest(location_name_name, item_json):  

     item_dictionary = json.loads(item_json)
     item_name_list = list(item_dictionary.keys())

     vals = []

     for i in range(1, len(item_name_list) + 1):
         vals.append({'location_name_name': location_name_name,
                      'item_name': item_name_list[i-1],
                      'item_unique_id': item_dictionary[item_name_list[i-1]][0],
                      'item_address': item_dictionary[item_name_list[i-1]][1]
                      })

     sql = ''' INSERT INTO test.public.item_manifest
   (location_name, item_name, item_unique_id, item_address)
     VALUES
        (%(location_name_list)s, %(item_name_list)s, %(item_unique_id_list)s, %(item_address_list)s)'''  

     conn = None

     try:
         # read database configuration
         params = setparams()
         # connect to the PostgreSQL database
         conn = psycopg2.connect(**params)
         # create a new cursor
         cur = conn.cursor()
         # execute the INSERT statement
         cur.executemany(sql, vals)
         # commit the changes to the database
         conn.commit()
         # close communication with the database
         cur.close()
     except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
         print(error)
     finally:
         if conn is not None:
              conn.close()
```

the generated SQL looks like this:

```
  INSERT INTO test.public.item_manifest
(location_name, item_name, item_unique_id, item_address)
VALUES
(%(location_name)s, %(item_name)s, %(item_unique_id)s, %(item_address)s)
```

[tutorial](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-python/insert/)

here is the json

```
      {'itemUniqueName1': ['item_ID_Number1', '<itemAddress1>', 'BooleanActive'], 'itemUniqueName2': ['item_ID_Number2', '<itemAddress2>', 'BooleanActive'],
```

Comment: Did you find out already which line of your code the error is referring to?

Comment: No it doesn’t say which line which is why I’m stumped

Comment: 1) You are not extracting JSON you are extracting from a `dict`, the conversion having been done by `item_dictionary = json.loads(item_json)`. 2) This `for i in nums(1, len(item_name_list))` can be simplified to `for ky in item_dictionary:  item_unique_id_list.append(item_dictionary[ky])`. 3) The `for i in nums ...` is where your problem is as `nums()` is returning a `range` not an `integer`. 4) As I have mentioned before strategically placed `print()`'s will help see what data structures you are actually dealing with.

Comment: `for i in range(1, len(item_name_list) + 1)` would accomplish the process you are attempting with `nums()`.

Comment: Also this `(%(location_name_list)s, %(item_name_list)s ...` is not going to work with `vals` as the parameter names (`%(location_name_list)s`) need to match the `val` dictionary keys(). Also the  `*_list` need to be a `list` of dictionaries with the keys matching the parameter names. That is not the case now. As mentioned before you need to set up a simple test case to learn how to use Python and psycopg2 and then build on that.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I was using a working test case I posted the tutorial I was expanding upon.  I had a bunch of print statements used all over to test and they all show that the objects are the correct type lists are lists etc I took them out of the code I posted to try for more clarity and to make it easier for people to read/follow

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I also added the results of the sql it looks correct to me

Comment: I was wrong about `nums()` it will return an `integer`, sorry for the misleading information. Show what is in `item_dictionary`. To be a little clearer `vals` needs to be a `list` of `dicts`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver no worries, I appreciate you helping me, I write code but never much with databases I updated to show the json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minimal example.

Create table:

```
create table items_test(id integer, fld_1 varchar);
```

Python code:

```
import json
import psycopg2

vals = json.loads('[{"id": 1, "fld_1": 2}, {"id": 3, "fld_1": 4}, {"id": 5, "fld_1": 6}]')

# vals                                                                                                                                                                      
# [{'id': 1, 'fld_1': 2}, {'id': 3, 'fld_1': 4}, {'id': 5, 'fld_1': 6}]

sql = "insert into items_test(id, fld_1) values(%(id)s, %(fld_1)s)"

cur.executemany(sql, vals)
con.commit()
```

In `psql`:

```
select * from items_test ;
 id | fld_1 
----+-------
  1 | 2
  3 | 4
  5 | 6
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarity, I was able to make it work I updated the original to the working code